# As an admin, how do I disable notifications from Facebook's comment moderation tool?

Tags: facebook, notifications, comments

We're using the [Facebook Comments Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) on our site for comments by users. The comment moderation is done using a developer app on developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/XXX.

Here, a number of moderators are specified. These can be added as moderator regardless of whether they have a developer profile with Facebook or just a regular Facebook profile.

When I add new moderators, they receive a notification on their private Facebook profile every time a new comment is added to our site. This means that they get flooded with notifications about comments.

There's seemingly no way to disable the comments. The Comment Moderation Tool has no options for notifications. The app does not show up in the user's [Notification Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications) or App Settings. Changing the notifications settings on the related Facebook Page does not help either.

So: **How do moderators of the Facebook Comments Plugin disable comment notifications on their private profiles?**

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, this is a know limitation. There is no way to disable notifications from the comments plugin. We are revising this functionality and a setting for this may be provided in the future.